# CPF throwinng SVC-SOCRECV: xdmp:http-post

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a CPF task which does an xdmp:http-post and I am getting `socket receive error: wait 10.239.12.22:53501-10.239.12.38:8080: Timeout (decodeResponseLine1)`

When I do the same  xdmp:http-post in query console I am not getting the socket receive error.. I tried setting `xdmp:set-request-time-limit(600)` before calling the xdmp:http-post but still does not work it seems to timeout around 1 min.. I also tried

```
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
   let $groupid := admin:group-get-id($config, "Default")
 admin:appserver-set-request-timeout($config, admin:appserver-get-id($config, $groupid, "content-repo"), 600)
```

but did not work.. Is there anything that I a missing ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request time limit is for the code that you are running itself. Xdmp http calls default to the http limit, but you can also override that via the `<timeout>` option to the method. See `xdmp:http-get` for details:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-get

HTH!

Comment: That fixed it, but now I get `SVC:EXTIME`, how can I increase the processing time

Comment: That is where you use [xdmp:set-request-time-limit](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-request-time-limit) for.